# Using one from the "grep" family. How do I get the lines I omitting the search term?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk, grep

Explaining:

I want to get all lines from Linux history command the have the `apt-get install`, but as I want to to just list what was installed I want also to join the lines in one and remove the `apt-get install` from it. It will be used later to create a command to install the same packages on another machine.
Can it be done only with one of the greps I must combine with `awk, sed etc`?

Comment: You could `grep` and `uniq` the results. Nonetheless, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Maybe ask this on http://www.askubuntu.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: I don't agree: this is script programming, not system maintenance

Comment: I doubt if it can be done alone with `grep`. Post your sample input/output.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I still do. This was a polite way of saying "no gimmeh teh codez" here. Which is the intent of the question.

Comment: If you look at grep's doc (man grep) you'll see that there's a switch which inverts the sense of the test. You can use that to select only lines which do not match the test, rather than those which do. HOWEVER... I believe there's actually a standard way to get a dump of the tools installed with `apt-get` which can be replayed to reinstall those tools; I'm suggest you go looking for that. (I seem to remember using it when I upgraded from one machine to another.)

Comment: Well. Can I move ti to superuser.com or askubuntu.com?

Comment: I've provided a grep-only answer.  As it is here on stackoverflow, I've also provided answers in awk and sed as well, aspiring to help people learn how to translate a skill in one tool to skill in another tool.  In that regard, it does belong here.  

The second half of my answer is more admin than coder.  It shares system-specific knowledge rather than coding knowledge.  I included it for completeness, but I see this question as a matter of _programming_ grep vs awk vs sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just `grep` (since you asked):

```
grep -Pow '^\s*(?:sudo\s+)?apt-get\s+install\s+\K.*' ~/.bash_history \
  |grep -Eow '\S+' |sort -u
```

This filters your history file for apt-get install commands and shows only the portion of those commands after the word install (`\K` is a great tool with `grep -Po`).  The second `grep` call puts each package on its own line so that the `sort` command can remove duplicates (`sort -u` shows only unique entries).  If you need it sorted chronologically, you cannot remove duplicate entries without a more powerful tool.

This requires libprce support in grep (common to most deployments these days) and isn't as elegant as other solutions, but it does satisfy your base requirement.

With just `awk`:

```
awk '
  /^sudo/ { sub(/^sudo/,"") }
  /^ *apt-get install/ {
    for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (!already[$i])
        print $i;
      already[$i] = 1
    }
  }' ~/.bash_history
```

This strips the optional sudo call at the beginning, then locates your `apt-get install` calls, and since it polls your history *file* rather than the output of the `history` *command*, there are no numbers (so while the earlier answers strip four cols, I strip only three).  This uses an awk hash to remove duplicates as it goes (preserving chronological order of first installation command).  If you don't care about duplicate removal, simply omit any line that references the already[$i] hash (so the only item inside the for loop is the `print $i` line).

With just `sed`:

```
sed 's/^sudo//; /^ *apt-get install */!d; s///; s/  */\n/g' ~/.bash_history |sort -u
```

Like the `awk` solution, this strips the optional `sudo` call and matches for the `apt-get install` command.  Matches are "not deleted" (which means non-matches are deleted) and then the matching portion ("apt-get install") is replaced with an empty string.  Then, each contiguous string of spaces is replaced with a newline.  Finally, it's all sorted and only unique output is displayed.  Note that my code will have some extra blank lines that may be annoying if not using `sort -u`.

---

Getting to what your actual goal may be:  Maybe you're just looking for installed packages?  You didn't manually specify them all as `apt-get install [package]` commands; some were pulled in as dependencies, others may not have made it to your history file due to multiple shells improperly folding their histories together, the install commands may be too old, or maybe you used a GUI like [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) or another tool like [aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude) or maybe some of these commands are in root's history rather than yours.

Perhaps you just want a list of installed packages:

```
dpkg -l |awk '/^i/ { print $2 }'
```

Perhaps you just want packages that were (somewhat) recently installed:

```
ls -tr /var/cache/apt/archives |sed 's/_.*//g' |sort -u
```

This actually shows everything you've downloaded, including items pending for install at some point since the last time your system cleaned that directory.  I left the `-tr` flag on `ls` in case you wanted chronological sorting (in which case, remove the `sort -u`).  Note that the chronological order here refers to the timestamp of each downloaded package, which I believe corresponds to the download time (though it could be the time of packaging at Ubuntu/Debian), which should be close enough.

Maybe you want to vet that against what is still installed (combining the two commands above).  First, save the output of the first command.  Then, run the second command and filter it by the output of the first command:

```
dpkg -l |awk '/^i/ { print $2 }' >/tmp/installed
ls -tr /var/cache/apt/archives |sed 's/_.*//g' |grep -Fxf /tmp/installed |sort -u
```

Like the above samples, this is constructed to let you remove the `sort -u` and get a chronological order.  It combines the above two methods; first, get a list of all installed packages and store them in `/tmp/installed` and second, list all recently downloaded packages, then show only the downloads that represent packages that are still installed.  Grep's `-f FILE` flag indicates that each line in FILE is a pattern to test (as logical OR), while the `-Fx` flag requires a literal match (a dot is a dot) of the whole line ("foo" does not match "foo-dev").

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to mention that I've saved the history inside a .txt file which includes the line numbers. So using your "regex class", teacher, I used this to obtain the lines:

`cat history_sudo.txt | grep "apt-get install" | grep -Pow '[0-9]*\K.*' | grep -Pow "apt-get install\K.*" | grep -Eow '\S+' | sort -u`

Comment: @tenshimsm: you can combine those first three greps:  `grep -Pow '.*apt-get install\K.*' history_sudo.txt |grep -Eow '\S+' |sort -u`

Answer (score 1):

No need for `grep`.

```
awk '/^apt-get install/ {for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) print($i)}'
```

should list all the installed packages, one per line. This won't work with irregular spacing, if there's a `sudo` in front or if there's a flag after the `apt-get` command, but it can be adapted to cope with all that.

Read as: for each line, if it starts with `apt-get install`, print all the fields except the first three (which will be the history number, `apt-get` and `install`, respectively). Note that field zero is the whole input line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
awk '/^apt-get install/{$1=$2=$3="";print}'
```